# Tileserver with time dimension

Tags: tile-map-service, wmts, tile-server, getcapabilities

We are preparing a Tileserver to serve tiles with a time dimension that updates every day. I was wondering what could be the best approach for that or the ideas we had are a good way.

To illustrate the problem:

We have observations for every full hour over 10 hours. That would be then 10 timesteps if implemented with a timeslider. The observations change every day.

Our idea was to make 10 layers which are accessible over a different layername. The layername would reflect the time of the observation(e.g. [ISO 8601 timestring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) or could be a simple number like 1, 2, 3, ... for every timestep with a corresponding meta.xml containing the date of the first layer and the interval between the timesteps.

Of course it would be the best if the meta.xml would be something like a WMS GetCapabilities. Different tile serving softwares as MapProxy or Mapcache serve some kind of metadata.xml for TMS and WMTS GetCapabilities for WMTS but seem unable to insert a time dimension. How could we implement this? There was a [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22107/wms-tile-cache-that-works-with-time-dimension) asking for implementations of the WMS time dimension for a WMTS but maybe in the meantime there where some developments. There is also a [blog post](https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14518214) on how the guys at nasa added a Dimension block to the WMTS GetCapabilites but I don't know which software they used for it. In the end we would prefer to use some existing standards over implementing our own structure.

Is this a good way to go? Do you think there is a better solution?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup: in the end we used the idea I described. Layers with different numbers and a meta.json. I think it is not the robustest way and at some point we will update it. Here you can see the [documentation](http://www.metgis.com/de/services/maps-api-doc/) and a [demo version](http://tiles.metgis.com/tiles-demo/)

Comment: Thanks. I just implemented something very similar with MapProxy and a Python script to (re-)generate the configuration YAML.