# Tile server for temporal data

Tags: tiles, time, tilecache, tilestache, spatio-temporal-data

Is there any tile server that is able to render tiles for temporal data?
I need to serve tiles for rain radar data and serve them in

> tilserverurl/{x}/{y}/{z}/{time} or similar way

I've done a little research and although there are several tile servers available TileStache, mod_tile, TileCache, TileStrata,... none of them seems to support a time dimension.

Is there any open source solution available that does the job and ideally supports on demand rendering and caching?

And if there isn't any tile server that supports that out of the box, any suggestion or explanation about how to implement that or how other people implement that on production will be very helpful.

By now my best idea is to implement some homemade tileserver that is backed by N gdal datasources or mapnik maps (one for time step).
In theory is not very difficult to make it working in a simple case but make it highly performant with render queue, caching and fine tune it is another history.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/110850/8673) and I am not aware of any tile server to support a time dimension.

The best solution I came up with, was to have different layers with the time dimension, see our [demo version](http://tiles.metgis.com/tiles-demo/).

[Weather.com](http://www.weather.com/weather/radar/interactive/l/l?animation=true) seems to have a similar approach as you can see in their tile ulrs (with a timestamp in the folder/layer structure):

```
http://tiles.weather.com/201212/en-US/0009/0001/Pi5CSuQ6xoV0MVoQ/0040/0/20160111061500/1/5/8/18/layer.png
```